# For $x,y \in \mathbb R - {2}$, $x * y = xy - 2x -2y + 6$. Find the identity element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I'm struggling to answer these kind of questions. In general, the way I set up these kind of problems is $a * e = a$, apply the particular operation to $a$ and $e$ and see if I can arrive at value for $e$. If $e$ depends on $a$, then $e$ doesn't exist so with the problem above, I arrived at $xe - 2x - 2e + 6 =x$ and I thought for sure identity DNE since it seems $e$ depends on $x$ but apparently the identity exists. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you isolate $e$ in the equation you got, you arrive at $e=\frac{3x-6}{x-2}=3$ after simplification, which does *not* depend on $x$.

Comment: what about it's inverse?

Comment: @curiousmind1995 What do you mean?

Comment: Thanks btw, I can't believe I didn't figure that out. What elements have an inverse s.t a * b = 3.

Comment: @curiousmind1995 Every element has an inverse. $a*b=3$ gives the equation of a hyperbola with asymptotes $x=2$ and $y=2$. Hence for a given $a\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{2\}$ there exists $b\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{2\}$ such that $a*b=3$. By commutativity we're done.

Answer (score 2):

If we take $x=3$ then $x*y=xy-2x-2y+6=3y-6-2y+6=y$

The operation is commutative so $3$ is in fact an identity element.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach id decent, checking for which value $e$ the equation $a * e$ holds. Then we need $e$ such that $ xe - 2x -2e + 6 = x  $ or $ \;;\; xe- 3x -2e + 6 = 0 $ i.e. $ (x - 2)(e - 3) = 0 $. Since we want to be general for each $x$ $x = 2$ does not make any sense. We try with $ e = 3 $. Then,

$a * 3 = 3x - 2x - 6 + 6 = x$ and $ 3 * a = 3a - 6 - 2a + 6 = a $ which works.